# Auto Redirect after login

Tags: multisite, redirect, login

In multisite this code redirect users (authors) to /wp-admin/post-new.php after the login ....but also redirects me (super admin) how can I prevent this?

```
function primary_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request_redirect_to, $user )
{
    if ($user->ID != 0) {
        $user_info = get_userdata($user->ID);
        if ($user_info->primary_blog) {
            $primary_url = get_blogaddress_by_id($user_info->primary_blog) . 'wp-admin/post-new.php';
            if ($primary_url) {
                wp_redirect($primary_url);
                die();
            }
        }
    }
    return $redirect_to;
} 
add_filter('login_redirect','primary_login_redirect', 100, 3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test against `is_super_admin()`. The following works in my testing:

```
function primary_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request_redirect_to, $user ) {
    if ( is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) && ! is_super_admin( $user->ID ) ) {
        if ( $user_info->primary_blog ) {
        $user_info = get_userdata( $user->ID );
            $primary_url = get_blogaddress_by_id( $user_info->primary_blog ) . 'wp-admin/post-new.php';
            if ( $primary_url ) {
                wp_redirect( $primary_url );
                die();
            }
        }
    }
    return $redirect_to;
} 
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'primary_login_redirect', 100, 3 );
```

The `is_a()` check clears some notices I got when logged out.

EDIT: If you want to do a different redirect URL for super admins only, I'd restructure to something like this:

```
function primary_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request_redirect_to, $user ) {
    if ( is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {
        if ( ! is_super_admin( $user->ID ) ) {
            $user_info = get_userdata( $user->ID );
            if ( $user_info->primary_blog )
                $primary_url = get_blogaddress_by_id( $user_info->primary_blog ) . 'wp-admin/post-new.php';
        } else { // super admins
            $primary_url = network_admin_url( 'sites.php' );
        }
        if ( $primary_url ) {
            wp_redirect( $primary_url );
            die();
        }
    }
    return $redirect_to;
} 
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'primary_login_redirect', 100, 3 );
```

Comment: thank you! I would like to redirect the super admin to /wp-admin/network/sites.php ...how can i do that? thanks !

Comment: You can just add an `else` with your separate redirect just before you return `$redirect_to` to the filter.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if you want to add an `else`, you might do better to split the first double test (the `is_a()` and `! is_super_admin()`) so you test against the `is_a()` first, then inside that the `is_super_admin()`, if that makes sense. That way, when you do the else, you still avoid the WP_Errors generated for logged-out users.

Comment: I get errors :( ....can you please rewrite the entire code with super admin redirect ? please :(

Comment: Try the second snippet in the edit.

Comment: Yeah I fixed that error before I commented. Try copying it again.